# How to save browser extension data in local storage?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, browser-extension

Can anyone tell me how to fix this one line and save this one variable so I can get on with my day?

I'm a total noob to browser extensions. My extension is intended to make changes to any webpage a user visits, and determines what changes to make by AJAX querying a database - that much works fine. To make my extension valuable for multiple users though, each user needs an ID number that persists across all domains.

My system works like this: on log-in at the extension's home site, the user gets a cookie with an encrypted ID number. I need to get that number from the cookie and save it in local storage, but I can't figure out how to save the ID number. The critical code is this:

```
//If we've just logged in we get our ID number from the cookie:

if(visitedURL.indexOf("log-in site name here") > -1){
    userId = getCookie("the cookie");

    //Then we make a key/value pair to hold our ID number
    userStorage = {
        key : userid
    }


    //And then, we attempt to save it. Uncommenting the following causes my extension to break.
    setting = browser.storage.local.set({
        userStorage;
    });
}
```

I used this as my guide:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: None, which frustrates me all the more. If I un-comment the offending code, the entire thing just breaks and nothing happens with it at all.

Comment: Since `userStorage` is already an object you might try passing it without the curly brackets: `browser.storage.local.set(userStorage)`

Comment: Drop the ; after userStorage..

Comment: @Charlie Weems : Thanks for the reply, but that didn't work.

Comment: @xs0 : That gets me one step closer. Now I've got the line uncommented and nothing breaks, but console.log(localStorage) is still showing a length of 0. It isn't broken now, but it isn't saving either...

Comment: Can you check that `browser.storage.local` is defined? I was unable to get it working in my console. `window.localStorage` worked though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @CharlieWeems: He's writing a browser extension.

Comment: @SLaks : Forgive my ignorance, but am I to gather, SLaks, from your most recent comment that Charlie's solution can't work for a browser extension?

Comment: @CharlieWeems : If your solution can work, I don't fully understand it, and I wasn't able to get it to do anything on a cursory investigation. If it can work, could you give me the whole line of code please?

Comment: @Truth, sorry, @SLaks is correct. It's not recommended to use `window.localStorage` in extension code.